# break long text into multiple lines in <p>

Tags: html, css

```
 <div class="row" style="width:700px" >
    <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10">
       <div class="messages msg_sent"  *>
                     <p style="white-space: pre-wrap">

m3rWa/5pgNMn006VHS6lJrkag1KK5aiwAJyYY7IHy+OBMYcl7R+Jw044xzRw/AdORhpj36AJ8j3DFZZjMUo3kLDKcVDd+UxRhGEFhxqfw/kj2+lExz7nPSjKRA0ybDLrygP2Cb2+9WQfUlC+tjVJaRGjhmMFEwsiTAjwH0DXM3U8Fd/aYyYHiicSD4KgUo5k3qJLVbROgA6kj0yC1eN0AgoE+O1Yz0SF1JmH76tBbMm74CmezE1g.box


</p>

       </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

I need to display the text, but the text is too long to show in one line as shown,

[image]
 how can I break it into multiple lines

Answer (score 3):

Use `word-wrap` to break long one line strings. Check docs for this [CSS Attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap). Also, note that this option has alias `overflow-wrap` so you can use any of theme since it is the same property.

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```